# Можно ли вывести вначале меньший, а затем больший из найденных корней без условного оператора?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика

Задача состоит из решения квадратного уравнения, при D > 0, A > 0.

Но необходимо:

> Вывести вначале меньший, а затем больший из найденных корней. Корни
>   квадратного уравнения находятся по формуле...

Это возможно вообще сделать не используя условия??
Язык JS.

Начало кода:

```
var a = +prompt("Введите значение коэффициента А (A > 0)", "");
    var b = +prompt("Введите значение коэффициента B", "");
    var c = +prompt("Введите значение коэффициента C", "");
    var discriminant = ( (b * b) - (4 * a * c) );
    var x1 = ( -b + Math.sqrt(discriminant) ) / ( 2 * a );
    var x2 = ( -b - Math.sqrt(discriminant) ) / ( 2 * a );
```

Comment: Math.max([x[, y[, …]]])

Comment: Ок, этот метод не видел, но я выведу наибольшее, а каким образом я выведу меньшее? Не вижу как я в коде пропишу, выбрать оставшийся X.
Или всё таки можно, если подумать?

upd. Есть, Math.min. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Ну на самый крайний случай `min(a,b)=(a+b+abs(a-b))/2` `max(a,b)=a+b-min(a,b)`

Comment: Если `A` - старший коэффциент, а `D` - дискриминант, и заведомо известно, что `A > 0` и `D > 0`, то это - задача для детского сада. В чем тогда затруднение?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот два корня:

```
x = (-b ± sqrt(d)) / (2*a)
```

Очевидно, что при a > 0 корень с `-` меньше, чем корень с `+`.

```
x_min = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2*a)
x_max = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2*a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)/[`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min):

```
Math.max(x, y)
Math.min(x, y)
```

Сниппет:

```js
// уравнение ax^2 + bx + c = 0
// например, x^2 - 3x + 2 = 0
let a = +1;
let b = -3;
let c = +2;

let d = Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c);
let root1 = (-b + d) / (2 * a);
let root2 = (-b - d) / (2 * a);

let rootMin = Math.min(root1, root2);
let rootMax = Math.max(root1, root2);
console.log(rootMin, rootMax);
```

Спасибо, в следующий раз буду тщательней искать, прежде чем задавать вопрос.

Comment: Если по условию можно,воспользуйтесь тернарным оператором

Comment: Раздел в котором находится задача подразумевает, что я знаю только как объявляются переменные и записываются значения в них.
+ элементарные операторы.

Comment: А разве нельзя без Min и Max определить какой из корней меньше, попробуйте подумать логически.

Comment: Почитайте очень внимательно код выражений первого корня и второго.

Comment: Я об этом подумал, но это решил что это будет как-то не по "программистскому" :)
Решение с max\min  мне больше нравится, иначе как-то неявно смотрится

Comment: @tranntus и зря, одна из основ программирования это логика, и отказываться от неё точно смысла нет. например есть числа a1 = 1 и a2 = 2, и нужно их вывести в порядке возрастания, что это надо сравнивать через sort? Кроме того в функции Min и Max if входит внутри.

Comment: Видимо, да, тогда задача была именно на это понимание.
А я если честно до сих пор не сообразил что к чему.
Вы правы.
Лол, только сейчас сообразил почему вариант с -дискриминантом будет всегда меньший. Хотя с первой секунды это предположил.

Итить я туп.